# Responsive background image Social Icons

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have that section:

```
<section class="socialIcons">
  <div class="fbIcon"></div>
  <div class="fbIcon"></div>
  <div class="fbIcon"></div>
  <div class="someClass">
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

and I want them to be all in one row. Left from each other and if client will resize browser at first social icons must resize and `someClass` div must stay in the right side. How can I do that? I even can't give `width` and `height` 100% to fb icons div since it disappears.

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbkyzcav/)

Comment: Do you want to apply those style when user is re-sizing window or you want to do it in certain width?

Comment: @alirezasafian now I've fixed width and height on icons. I want them to change on window resizing. for example percentage width but when I'm doing it doesn't work

Comment: @Daenu I've tried to do that using percentage width but If that width is less than 80px it crops from image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbkyzcav/2/)

```
    .fbIcon {
       background: url(http://i.imgur.com/tLHwYNw.png) no-repeat;
       height: 80px;
       width: 80px;
       float: left;
       margin-right: 20px;
       margin-top: 12px;
       cursor: pointer;
       display:inline-block;
   }

.someClass {
    width: 50%;
    height: 90px;
    background: #ff7043;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.someClass > h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 90px;
}
```

or

[JSFiddle Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbkyzcav/3/)

```
    .fbIcon {
    width: 14%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

.someClass {
    width: 50%;
    height: 90px;
    background: #ff7043;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.someClass > h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not my cleanest work, but you can clean it up: https://jsfiddle.net/JTBennett/Lbkyzcav/4/

Hopefully that's close to what you were asking for, but it's hard to tell by your description...

I'd try to avoid using absolute positioning, though you can do it with this:

```
position:absolute; right:0;
```

If you specify a height for a wrapper and float it right with your styled wrapper in there, it's a little cleaner - inherent position is the better way to go in my opinion.

It's just a matter of finding the right heights and widths now.